# How to track the path of the file On some other Application

Tags: android, file, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an requirement on my app that is , i have to track the file path and second i have to track the time of the file if that file is opened in some other application . I had researched everything but still not figuring out how to start . I know it's challenging and brain stroke implementation , but i need proper idea to move ahead .

I have achieved to create a file (file is of any kind .pdf/.docs etc)inside a folder . Now what i need if any one open the file in any other app then i have to first get the path of the file and secondly i have to track the time at what time the file is opened and closed . Here is the way i created the folder and dumped the file inside it . Now i have to read the file path and file opened in other app .

```
@Override
    protected File doInBackground(FileMetadata... params) {
        FileMetadata metadata = params[0];
        //pathOfFileToSaved --> eg flight/ticket/vilash.pdf , flight/other/suman.docs
        String folder_name = pathOfFileToSaved;

       // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);

        try {
            File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folder_name);
            Log.e("pathoffile",""+path);
            File file = new File(path, metadata.getName());

            // Make sure the Downloads directory exists.
            if (!path.exists()) {
                if (!path.mkdirs()) {
                    mException = new RuntimeException("Unable to create directory: " + path);
                }
            } else if (!path.isDirectory()) {
                mException = new IllegalStateException("Download path is not a directory: " + path);
                return null;
            }

            // Download the file.
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                mDbxClient.files().download(metadata.getPathLower(), metadata.getRev())
                    .download(outputStream);
            }

            // Tell android about the file
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
            mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

            return file;
        } catch (DbxException | IOException e) {
            mException = e;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is 'tracking a file path'?

Comment: ?????? You did not explain what tracking that path would be. Moreover that path does not exist.

Comment: means my file is saved in which path when it is opened in some other application suppose i have pdf viewer App installed in my device and i have to read this file vilash.pdf which is located in my device memory at this path  eg: flight/ticket/vilash.pdf , then my app should return this path flight/ticket/vilash,pdf(i.e tracking of file )

Comment: Why do you have to read that file if it should be opened in a different application? And if you saved the file yourself then you already know the path. So why should another app be involved.

Comment: Actually i have to see , how much time user spent on my file . Suppose User can go to filemanager and go to this path flight/ticket/vilash,pdf and open the vilash,pdf file and read it in say pdf viewer Application , then i want my app to know which file he is opened in the pdfviewer so i need the path of file , if he is actually reading the file from my folder then i have to track the time that he spent on my file. otherwise if he is reading from other then my folder then i don't have to track time or path of the file. Hope you get the scenerio